# Is it possible to have a different language when calling my odata service than the logon language of my SAP UI5 application?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I would like to call my odata service in a way that the system language of the NetWeaver gateway is different from the logon language in my SAP UI5 application

For example, a user logs into the UI5 application in German but when the service is called, I want the backend system-language to be in English.

Is there a way to do that, maybe by setting a specific header property in the model or a url parameter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a SAP OData service is handled by SAP via the ICF, doesn't it work as explained here: [SAP Library - Determining the Logon Language](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/SAP_NETWEAVER_AS_ABAP_752/7.52.5/en-US?q=Determining%20the%20Logon%20Language)

Comment: @SandraRossi First, thanks for the link. Within the header the field **accept-language** is provided but it cannot be changed from within the application.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so you log into a app.. which is in german and you want to call your oData Service based on the backend system language? or what you mean with 
**"I want the backend system-language to be in English."** ?

as parameter in your app `sap-language=DE` let this as default and set the backend language to `en`

Comment: I want the oData service to be English if a the country chosen in a combobox is UK or US.

Comment: Just pass a key to a filter to the odataserivce (needs also to adjust in the backend)

Comment: I added more information within my service but I also had to provide more data in the bapis I am calling. By that, the logon language was ignored and the one I sent was then used. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For your question, I can relate two ways possible -

1. Either you using some native programming language (in my case it is android (Java/Kotlin)):

> use **accept-language** header key to pass
> the desired language short-form. in the case of German, it is 'DE'.

2. Or you are running services on the browser:

> use **sap-language** as an additional header parameter in your URL and pass the desired language.

> URL example:
> http://serverhost:port/namespace/storename/XYZSet?sap-language='DE'